# Reset post IDs with all post meta

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I imported posts from an old website.
Posts from the new website have IDs under 100.
Posts from the old website have IDs above 9934.

I tried to change manually the post IDs in phpmyadmin in order to follow the "small" IDs from my new website (101, 102, 103...). The problem is that I lost all the post_meta related to the old posts (Thats' normal because I didn't change the Ids for the post_meta). Because I can't change manually all post meta related IDs (Many custom fields), I am looking for a solution to "reset" all my post IDs.

I don't mind to reset all my posts, even the ones I created in the new website. **The posts have to keep their post_meta.**

What do you suggest to do that ?

Comment: Why do you even need to change the IDs?

Comment: I am using a specific number logic for a plugin like this : 123[postID]00[mylogique]123[postID] => Specific ID for specific use. Because my server is blocked to 32MB, I can be blocked very fast, so i would like to reorganize it in order to avoid big IDs even before I start

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like you’re misusing IDs. You should elaborate on what exactly you’re trying to do in your question, because from the outside it looks like a pointless exercise. I can’t imagine any situation where high IDs are going to cause a problem, even with only 32mb memory.

Comment: The problem is because for a specific use, an ID from a custom post type will be this way : [postID][code][postID] (Thats a trick from my company to identify specific stuff)), I can be blocked very fast. Now, if you think there is no way to reset all posts IDs in a simple way, then OK, I will find another solution

Comment: Honestly there is no way to identify the old Post IDs and "reset" them. Your only real option is to revert to a backup copy of the database where the old Post IDs existed. From there, you could try using WP Export, reinstalling WP, and using WP Import to see if that resets the post IDs to the lowest numbers possible, but as Jacob mentioned, it's very unlikely that switching to lower post IDs would have any performance impact.